# Azure email login signup b2c iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am new to Azure.I am building native iOS app which has email login/signup using azure active directory B2C.I am able to login and signup but the issue is that the redirect url is not working.On successful login or signUp i am still on the browser rather the coming back to my app.

CODE

```
let kTenantName = "AppName"
let kSignupOrSigninPolicy = "B2C_1_signupPolicy"

let kClientId = "clientId"
let kRedirectUri = "https://appname.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback"
let kEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/........"

@IBAction func bt_login(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Signing in")
    let authorizationEndpoint = NSURL(string: kEndpoint)!
    let tokenEndpoint = NSURL(string: kEndpoint)!
    let configuration = OIDServiceConfiguration(authorizationEndpoint: authorizationEndpoint, tokenEndpoint: tokenEndpoint)
    let request = OIDAuthorizationRequest(configuration: configuration, clientId: kClientId, scopes: [OIDScopeOpenID, OIDScopeProfile], redirectURL: NSURL(string: kRedirectUri)!, responseType: OIDResponseTypeCode, additionalParameters: nil)
    var appDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate);
    appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authStateByPresentingAuthorizationRequest(request, presentingViewController: self) { (authState, error) in
        if (authState != nil) {
            print("Got ID token: \(authState!.lastTokenResponse!.idToken)")
        }
        else {
            print("Authorization error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

I have added the same redirect url in the `info.plist` file.
Also i have added the redirect url to azure web-portal in `Authentication/Authorization->ALLOWED EXTERNAL REDIRECT URLS` section.

Answer (score 1):

Your redirect URL should look something com.onmicrosoft.contoso.appname://redirect/path. See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration#register-a-mobile-or-native-app) for instructions on how to register a native app and configure the redirect URI.

> Also i have added the redirect url to azure web-portal in Authentication/Authorization->ALLOWED EXTERNAL REDIRECT URLS section.

That is not the right place. Please follow the steps in the link above.